# Trying to customize RadioButton Cell and Column for DataGridView Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, datagridview

I am relying on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882(vs.80).aspx to implement the usage of radio buttons in the cells of the DataGridView control. However, I am running in circles because I'm not sure what I should be doing.

So far, I have the class set up as shown in the link, but how do I implement these methods?

```
    /// Represents the cell's current formatted value
    public virtual object EditingCellFormattedValue

    /// Keeps track of whether the cell's value has changed or not.
    public virtual bool EditingCellValueChanged

    /// Returns the current formatted value of the cell
    public virtual object GetEditingCellFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)

    /// Called by the grid when the cell enters editing mode. 
    public virtual void PrepareEditingCellForEdit(bool selectAll)
```

If there is a better way to incorporate radio buttons into DataGridViews or ListViews, please let me know! Otherwise, I'd really appreciate some suggestions on how to get this custom class to work.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Implemented what I needed according to the documentation, but they show up as combo boxes. How do I do this correctly to display radio buttons?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace B3.CatapultProjectUserInterfaceKit.DialogsContribution
{
    public class DataGridViewRadioButtonColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        private DataGridViewRadioButtonCell RadioButtonCellTemplate;

        public DataGridViewRadioButtonColumn()
            : base(new DataGridViewRadioButtonCell())
        {
        }

        public int MaxDisplayedItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.RadioButtonCellTemplate == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation cannot be completed because this DataGridViewColumn does not have a CellTemplate.");
                }
                return this.RadioButtonCellTemplate.MaxDisplayedItems;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.MaxDisplayedItems != value)
                {
                    this.RadioButtonCellTemplate.MaxDisplayedItems = value;
                    if (this.DataGridView != null)
                    {
                        DataGridViewRowCollection dataGridViewRows = this.DataGridView.Rows;
                        int rowCount = dataGridViewRows.Count;
                        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
                        {
                            DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = dataGridViewRows.SharedRow(rowIndex);
                            DataGridViewRadioButtonCell dataGridViewCell = dataGridViewRow.Cells[this.Index] as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell;
                            if (dataGridViewCell != null)
                            {
                                dataGridViewCell.MaxDisplayedItemsInternal = value;
                            }
                        }
                        this.DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(this.Index);
                        // TODO: Add code to autosize the column and rows, the column headers,
                        // the row headers, depending on the autosize settings of the grid.
                        // The DataGridView control does not expose a public method that takes care of this.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CellTemplate;
            }
            set
            {
                DataGridViewRadioButtonCell dataGridViewRadioButtonCell = value as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell;
                if (value != null && dataGridViewRadioButtonCell == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Value provided for CellTemplate must be of type DataGridViewRadioButtonCell or derive from it.");
                }
                base.CellTemplate = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataGridViewRadioButtonCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell, IDataGridViewEditingCell
    {
        private int maxDisplayedItems;       // Caches the value of the MaxDisplayedItems property
        private object formattedValue;
        private bool valueChanged = false;

        public DataGridViewRadioButtonCell()
        {
            this.maxDisplayedItems = 1;
        }

        public int MaxDisplayedItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this.maxDisplayedItems;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 1 || value > 100)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MaxDisplayedItems");
                }
                this.maxDisplayedItems = value;

                if (this.DataGridView != null && !this.DataGridView.IsDisposed && !this.DataGridView.Disposing)
                {
                    if (this.RowIndex == -1)
                    {
                        // Invalidate and autosize column
                        this.DataGridView.InvalidateColumn(this.ColumnIndex);

                        // TODO: Add code to autosize the cell's column, the rows, the column headers 
                        // and the row headers depending on their autosize settings.
                        // The DataGridView control does not expose a public method that takes care of this.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The DataGridView control exposes a public method called UpdateCellValue
                        // that invalidates the cell so that it gets repainted and also triggers all
                        // the necessary autosizing: the cell's column and/or row, the column headers
                        // and the row headers are autosized depending on their autosize settings.
                        this.DataGridView.UpdateCellValue(this.ColumnIndex, this.RowIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        internal int MaxDisplayedItemsInternal
        {
            set
            {
                Debug.Assert(value >= 1 && value <= 100);
                this.maxDisplayedItems = value;
            }
        }

        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return null since no editing control is used for the editing experience.
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override object Clone()
        {
            DataGridViewRadioButtonCell dataGridViewCell = base.Clone() as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell;
            if (dataGridViewCell != null)
            {
                dataGridViewCell.MaxDisplayedItems = this.MaxDisplayedItems;
            }
            return dataGridViewCell;
        }

        protected override bool ContentClickUnsharesRow(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Point ptCurrentCell = this.DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;
            return ptCurrentCell.X == this.ColumnIndex &&
                   ptCurrentCell.Y == e.RowIndex &&
                   this.DataGridView.IsCurrentCellInEditMode;
        }

        /// Represents the cell's current formatted value
        public virtual object EditingCellFormattedValue
        {
            get { return formattedValue; }
            set { formattedValue = value; }
        }

        /// Keeps track of whether the cell's value has changed or not.
        public virtual bool EditingCellValueChanged
        {
            get { return valueChanged; }
            set { valueChanged = value; }
        }

        /// Returns the current formatted value of the cell
        public virtual object GetEditingCellFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return formattedValue;
        }

        /// Called by the grid when the cell enters editing mode. 
        public virtual void PrepareEditingCellForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to allow DataGridView to select only one row at a time? and when u select the another then previous one should be unchecked? right?

Comment: I have two columns of check boxes in each row. In each row, I want to check one and not the other. And if I click the other, I want to uncheck the previous one. None are the rows are dependent on each other. @Shell